# Is it possible to host WebMethods and an ASP.NET app on the same AppDomain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, appdomain

I have added some [web methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to my ASP.NET page like the following to enable [AJAX calls using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) on the client side of my application:

```
public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Page load logic...
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string MyWebMethod()
    {
        // web method logic...
    }
}
```

However, I noticed using the debugger that my web methods are being processed on a different [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) than my ASP.NET Page's AppDomain, hence each one of them has its own set of static variables which is causing me some trouble.

So I would like to know if it's somehow possible to host WebMethods (or a web-service) and an ASP.NET app on the same AppDomain, enabling both of them access to the same set of static variables?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

I'm hosting my app on IIS 7.0

**EDIT 2**

As Jupaol's answer clearly shows it is possible to host WebMethods and an ASP.NET page on the same appDomain, nevertheless here is what I found after running more tests:

If my jQuery.ajax call sets its URL like this:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "/MyFolder/MyPage.aspx/MyWebMethod",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: AjaxSuccess,
         error: AjaxError
});
```

IIS creates two appDomains on my Web site (same [web site key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524661%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)), one for the page request and another for the WebMethod request. Their [FriendlyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.friendlyname.aspx) are showed below:

- "/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-6-129872125368848248" (WebMethod)
- "/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/WebApp-5-129872125273487796" (ASP.NET page request)

However, if the jQuery.ajax call URL is set like this:

```
$.ajax({
         url: "MyPage.aspx/MyWebMethod",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: AjaxSuccess,
         error: AjaxError
});
```

Only one appDomain gets created to serve both requests:

- "/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/WebApp-7-129872126989518526"

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find an explanation for this behaviour, and the only thing I can think of that may be related to this issue is that my web site uses [https](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) on some pages and not in others.

Comment: How did you realized that? As far as I know, that's not possible, they could be being executed on different threads but of the same AppDomain

Comment: I checked the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.currentdomain.aspx) both when Page_Load and MyWebMethod were executed and they didn't match.

Comment: I've never seen this in the debugger, how can you see this?  Is the web service in your project/solution?  And why in the world would a web service need access to static variables of the calling application?  A web service is supposed to be a black box, you pass any data to it, as long as it conforms to the WSDL, and it does what it does, needing nothing more than that, according to the WSDL.  None of the applications accessing it need know how it works.  This is a really unusual question.  It should never need access to the static variables of the app consuming it, it is standalone.

Comment: continued... Are you declaring AppDomians in your code?  If so, why?  Your posted code is a web method.  A web service is something similar, but very different, too.  Which is it?  The title of this may be misleading.  And what is the reason for making the web method static?  There are lots of questions here.

Comment: @GrayFox374 It's not a web service, they are called Page Methods which behave like Web Services

Comment: It says "Is it possible to host a web-service and an ASP.NET app on the same AppDomain?", but there is no web service...?  Can you edit that?

Comment: @GrayFox374 *How can you see this*: Simply check AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id; *Is the web service in your project/solution?*: Yes, it is declared in the same project as my ASP.NET app; *AppDomians in your code?*: No I'm not, just checking those IIS has assigned me; *Which is it?*: Actually I tried both a web-service (asmx) and ASP.NET web methods, and they exhibited the same behavior, i.e., the ran in different appDomains; *reason for making the web method static?*: The web-service has instance methods, but in aspx pages it is necessary to declare them static to make them visible to jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that you are comparing the AppDomain's ID???

I just made an experiment and they **do belong to the same AppDomain**

That could not always be true if you are explicitly creating AppDomains in code.

Example: (I just updated an old example I had, focus on the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id`)

### Code Behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblMessage.Text += "AppDomain ID: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id.ToString() + "<br/>";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string Execute1()
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string r = string.Empty;
        var o = Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            r = "My Name1: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Background thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        }, Scheduler.NewThread);
        o.First();
        r += " Main thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
        r += " AppDomain ID: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Id.ToString();
        r = j.Serialize(new { res = r });
        return r;
    }
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Did you host your application in IIS or using the ASP.NET development server?

Comment: In both ASP.Net development server and IIS 7 in Windows 7, and they have the same AppDomain ID.

Comment: After reading your answer I decided to run my tests again, and I discovered that depending on how I define my Page URL in the jQuery ajax call sometimes I get two different AppDomainIds and sometimes the same (as in your example). I will investigate this a bit more and then let you know the results.

Comment: A possible reason would be if you have deployed your service in two different Web Applications and depending on how you call the service, you are reaching a different application therefore a different AppDomain, to avoid this problem I would recommend you to call the service as follows: `<%: this.ResolveClientUrl("~/YourPageName.aspx/YourMethod") %>`